# Show/Hide <DIV> Based on <SELECT> Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Can anyone help point out to me what's stopping this code that works perfectly fine with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m16gupz1/) from working in [my webpage](http://cpugrade.com/gtav-sysreq.php)?

I have been trying to fix this for the past couple of hours, and no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to trigger. I have a feeling it's going to be something really simple and stupid that's completely gone over my head, but it's slowly ticking me off and hindering progress on other things that rely on this.

I appreciate any help provided, thank you.

```
$('#select-os').change( function() {
    if (this.value == "r") {
        $('.wont').show();
        $('.ready, .will').hide();
    }
    else if (this.value == "g") {
        $('.will').show();
        $('.ready, .wont').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: try wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function () { your_code });`

Comment: @pr0metheus WOW, that was a major fail on my part. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a `document.ready` try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('#select-os').change( function() {
    if (this.value == "r") {
        $('.wont').show();
        $('.ready, .will').hide();
    }
    else if (this.value == "g") {
        $('.will').show();
        $('.ready, .wont').hide();
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Josh, that's exactly what it was. I can't believe something so trivial went unnoticed.